# Windows 10 never sleeps

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Most guides talk about changing simple windows sleep settings like timeouts, preventing wake on lan, setting devices to disable "let this wake the computer" and so on. I even disabled the mouse and keyboard (wireless) from waking the computer (which I would prefer they do, but I turned them off for now for testing).

I've done all of them. I've also tried the following:

```
powercfg /request (shows none across the board)
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed (NONE)
powercfg /energy (generates report showing nothing that would prevent sleep)
```

The only thing that seems bad in the report is this:

```
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Selective Suspend
This device did not enter the USB Selective Suspend state. Processor power management may be prevented when this USB device is not in the Selective Suspend state. Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.
Device Name Generic USB Hub
Host Controller ID  PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7808
Host Controller Location    PCI bus 0, device 19, function 2
Device ID   USB\VID_043D&PID_0029
Port Path   5,1
```

But it specifically says it doesn't prevent it from sleeping.

Anyway, I tried setting the sleep timer to one minute and it ignores it. Nothing happens at all. If I forget to turn it off manually, it runs all night and all day wasting power and making heat for no reason. I can't figure out why it won't behave.

Note that it's a media computer so it auto-logs in to an account and runs KODI which is almost always on in the background. It will sleep if you select it from the menu or press the power button, but never on its own.

All windows updates are installed as are the current windows "big" updates 1903, etc. There are some optional driver updates that don't appear important and some "preview" update for version 2004 (KB4577063) which I don't want to install without reason.

Comment: This was a bug introduced in an update a few weeks back, unsure if you have the problem KB update installed, but you should be able to determine whether or not that's the issue via google to find the applicable KB number and verify if it's installed

Comment: There are no optional updates listed for me other than the ones I mentioned.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you ever fix this? The only unusual thing about my setup is I'm using a KVM, but I don't see why that should matter.